# JavaScript argument function call with unknown amount of argumnts

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function that loops over elements and calls a function for each class with different amount of arguments.

maybe I can bind them somehow?
obviously this code doesn't work , so it's just for reference:

```
function elementsLoop(className, fn, ...args) {
  let elems = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  for(const elem of elems) {
    fn(elem, ...args);
  }
}

let a = (elem, x, y, z) => {
  //do something with 'elem' and x y ,z
}

let b = (elem) => {
  //do something with 'elem'
}
let c = (elem, t) => {
  //do something with 'elem' and t
}

elementsLoop('some-class', a, [x,y,z]);
elementsLoop('some-class', b, []);
elementsLoop('some-class', c, [t]);
```

Here Is my original approach and I'm just woundering how can I do It differently:

```
let getElements = (className) => {
  return document.getElementsByClassName(className);
}

function a(className, x, y, z) {
  let elems = getElements(className);
  for(const el of elems){
    //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: `function elementsLoop (className , fn , ...args)` -> `function elementsLoop (className , fn , args)` or alternatively `elementsLoop('some-class' , a , [x,y,z]);` -> `elementsLoop('some-class' , a , x,y,z);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to pass an array as argument list.

```
fn.apply(null, [elem , ...args]);
```

Also, you probably want to change the function call to:

```
elementsLoop('some-class' , a , x, y, z);
```

Comment: can I ask what doe's the 'null' do? @gen_Eric

Comment: @AndyR This answer will only allow 3 arguments. The null sets the `this` value in the fn function to null.

Comment: @AndyR The 1st argument to `.apply()` is what you want to become `this` inside the function you are calling.  We don't really care about that here, so `null`.

Comment: @gen_Eric So i can use it in eventListeners, is that right?

Comment: @AndyR I don't see why not

Answer (score 1):

When a function is defined like so: `function fun(...abc) {}`, it is called like this: `fun(1, 2, 3)`.

```js
function elementsLoop(className, fn, ...args){
  let elems = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  for(const elem of elems){
    fn(elem, ...args);
  }
}

let a = (elem, x, y, z) => {
  //do something with 'elem' and x y ,z
}

let b = (elem) => {
  //do something with 'elem'
}

let c = (elem, t) => {
  //do something with 'elem' and t
}

elementsLoop('some-class', a, x, y, z);
elementsLoop('some-class', b);
elementsLoop('some-class', c, t);
```